# Spring Cloud Zuul + OAuth Error CORS

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm using Spring Boot Cloud + OAuth2 Auth system, but I'm having a problem in the auth method. When I try to authenticate with my server the Zuul gateway is not sending the headers params, but if I try to authenticate directly to my oauth server I don't have a problem. The problem only happens when I try to authenticate through the Zuul gateway.

Auth Response:

> error_description :"Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Request Header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:pt,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Authorization:Basic <MySecretToken>
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
DNT:1
Host:localhost:8181
Origin:http://localhost:9980
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:9980/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.11 Safari/537.36
```

OAuth Server Logging with Zuul Request:

```
2016-03-07 16:41:37.826 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.826 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.826 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.826 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@541da561
2016-03-07 16:41:37.826 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.827 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.827 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.827 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.828 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.828 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.828 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90556c3e: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de6: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.1.40; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.828 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.829 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.829 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.829 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-03-07 16:41:37.829 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?password=myPassword&grant_type=password&username=system; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2016-03-07 16:41:37.829 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90556c3e: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@1de6: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.1.40; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-03-07 16:41:37.838 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@59b8fe9, returned: -1
2016-03-07 16:41:37.846 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

Notes that in the filter 5 of 11 the filter must be executed, but it was not.

Look now the log of the some server but without the gateway:

```
2016-03-07 16:51:16.641 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.641 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.641 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.641 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@541da561
2016-03-07 16:51:16.641 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.641 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/logout'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.641 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.644 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'gateway'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.645 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-03-07 16:51:16.667 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b0a7f710: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@f4ba4644: Username: gateway; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
2016-03-07 16:51:16.667 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.667 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.667 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.667 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@b0a7f710: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@f4ba4644: Username: gateway; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.667 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.668 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@727809f6
2016-03-07 16:51:16.668 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-03-07 16:51:16.668 DEBUG 31205 --- [nio-9190-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=system&password=myPassword at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
```

Now look at the second log, you will see that in the filter 5 of 11 the filter was accepted.

Here is the Gateway module setup information:

https://gist.github.com/tiarebalbi/07aaa61f84d3ea3822e0

---

**Update:**

Below the CorsFilter used in the gateway:
https://gist.github.com/tiarebalbi/ce5f6fc9691e1a6e3aaa

**Debug Information:**

What I noticed is that the gateway receives all header parameters, but the authentication server doesn't.

Gateway:

[image: Parameters in the Gateway]

OAuth Server:

[image: OAuthServer]

---

**Solution:**

Reviewing the document i saw the description about the Sensitives Headers and as we can see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/ZuulProperties.java#L127-L128) and [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers) the Authorization is one of the list and because of this it wasn't sent to the others services.

Code after the update:

```
zuul:
  ignored-services: "*"
  prefix: /v1
  routes:
    auth-server:
      path: /auth/**
      sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, adding the `sensitive-headers` worked!

```
zuul.routes.myApi1.path=/api/**
zuul.routes.myApi1.url=http://localhost:8090/myApi/
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```